# Android, Java: ExecutorService execute after shutdown

Tags: java, android

I have a `ExecutorService`:

```
private final ExecutorService listenDataExecutorService = 
                              Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

In same case I need executor to stop doing his job.
For this I call `listenDataExecutorService.shutdown();`

Then after some time, I need this executor to do this job again.
But when I call `listenDataExecutorService.execute()` exception is thrown.

How can I execute new task for executor after `shutdown` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once an executor service has been shut down it can't be reactivated. Create a new executor service to restart execution:

```
listenDataExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

(You'd have to drop the `final` modifier though.)

Another option is to cancel all pending tasks instead, and then reschedule them when you want to resume execution.

Comment: Is there other way to clean current executor tasks except "shutdown" ?

Comment: If you use ThreadPoolExecutor you have a remove(Runnable) operation.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, I'd suggest you create a higher level service with start/pause/resume/stop methods which in turn manage en executor service internally.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove `final` access level modifier to re-create `ExecutorService` at latter stage. `final`  modifier does not allow you to change the reference of `ExecutorService` later during re-initialization.

> In same case I need executor to stop doing his job. For this I call `listenDataExecutorService.shutdown();`

You have to call three methods in a right sequence to shutdown the `ExecutorService`: `shutdown, awaitTermination, shutdownNow`

Have a look at  below post:

[How to properly shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-properly-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)

> Then after some time, I need this executor to do this job again. But when I call `listenDataExecutorService.execute()` exception is thrown.
>
> How can I execute new task for executor after shutdown ?

Before you call `execute` on that `ExecutorService`, that service should not be in `shutdown` state. Make sure that `ExecutorService` is in proper state to accept tasks => Your application code should properly handle "***shutdown***" and "***re-creation***" of `ExecutorService`.