# How to properly shutdown java ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, shutdown

I have a simple java `ExecutorService` that runs some task objects (implements `Callable`).

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
List<CallableTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
// ... create some tasks
for (CallableTask task : tasks) {
 Future future = exec.submit(task);
 result = (String) future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 // TASKS load some classes and invoke their methods (they may create additional threads)
 // ... catch interruptions and timeouts
}
exec.shutdownNow();
```

After all tasks are finished (either DONE or TIMEOUT-ed), I try to shutdown the executor, but it wont stop: `exec.isTerminated() = FALSE.`
I suspect that some tasks that are timeouted are not properly terminated.

And yes, I know that executor's shutdown is not guaranteing anything:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop
>         processing actively executing tasks.  For example, typical
>         implementations will cancel via {@link Thread#interrupt}, so any
>        task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

My question is, is there a way to ensure those (task) threads will terminate?
The best solution I came up with, is to call the `System.exit()` at the end of my program, but that is plain silly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shutdown an ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504172/how-to-shutdown-an-executorservice)

Answer (score 29):

Recommended way from Oracle API documentation page of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```

If your pool is taking more time to shutdown, you can change

```
if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

to

```
while (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

---

#### A brief summary of the shutdown related methods

[*shutdown()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown--):

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

[*shutdownNow()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow--):

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

[*awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have control of those tasks ? i.e. are you creating those yourself ? I suspect somewhere in those a thread interrupt is being ignored e.g.

```
try {
  ....
}
catch {InterruptedException e) {
   // do nothing
}
```

When an InterruptedException is thrown, the interrupt flag on the thread needs to be reset, otherwise the thread will not exit. See [here for more info](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html).

Unfortunately you may be using a library that doesn't obey this, in which case you can't easily circumvent this. In that case one heavyweight option is to fork off a sub process to perform the job of the `Callable`, and that will clear up all resources upon process exit. Heavyweight and possibly non-trivial, but reliable.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that those task can freely invoke custom threads if they like, so I need a solution that kills everything that task has created...

Comment: @N10 - yes. You'll need some lifecycle management around your tasks

Comment: Problem is, tasks actually loads other classes and invokes their methods (which can be literally anything). I need a way to terminate those (invoked methods) threads. I thought that Timeout terminates them, but it seems that is not the thing...