# The use of executor.shutdown()

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

Look at the following piece of code:

```
     public void pinger()
     {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, start, rate, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();
     }
```

Is there any use of writing the **shutdown command** in this case? Different clients would create their own runnable objects and invoke this function.

Comment: Why would you like to shutdown immediately after fixing a rate?

Comment: Please have a look at [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()) of this method. Creating new thread pool for each thread/runnable is not an advisable design. It can lead expensive use of resources. Think about sponsoring 1000 threads at a time. Thread pool should be just once with pool of 10 threads(as per resources available) in this case and use it globally for all requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you shutdown an executor, no new task will be accepted. Since you create a new one inside the pinger method every task has its own executor. A shutdown as you write will only free resource once the corrent task is terminated.

Comment: So when a new client with a new runnable object invokes the pinger() method, will it create issues, given the fact that the execution of the previous client was shutdown?

Comment: No, because you are creating a new executor for the new runnable. So the new task is indipendent from the one before.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

1. You should not create `Executor` for each client request.
2. Create `Executor` out side of client request and submit tasks to `Executor`
3. When you decide that you should not accept new tasks to `Executor`, then shutdown the executor. The right way of shutting down `Executor` is explained in below post:

[How to forcefully shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-forcefully-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)