# Thread join vs ExecutorService.awaitTermination

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a group of threads which all need to be executed in parallel and I must wait on all of them to complete.

Should I use the plain old `Thread` or the `ExecutorService` ? for the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` I must give a certain time that I'm willing to wait but for `Thread.join` I must not.

I don't do anything with the results that the threads give , I don't need any `futures`.

EDIT:

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(kThreads);
    List<Callable<Void>> calls = new LinkedList<>();

        container.forEach(
                calls.add(() -> { //creating a thread/task 
                    BufferedImage scaledBufferedImage=imageService.scale(...);

                    imageService.transferToAWS(...);
                    return null;
                })
        );
        es.invokeAll(calls); //executes each task
        es.shutdown(); //ensure that no new tasks will be accepted
        es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); //wait for all tasks to finish

return kLinksToTheScaledImages;
```

Comment: If you don't do anything with the results then why do you need to wait at all?If you need to wait until they're done then you _will_ use the results in some way.

Comment: Not really. You could let those threads do some kind of data processing and need to wait for them all to finish until you a) process the next batch of data. b) close the connection to a data source (not necessary a DB) c) can simply show a feedback to the user like "Done". I could continue with a few more examples, but the comment box is nearly full.

Comment: What is the environment? Do you have a simple JavaSE program running on a local machine, or do you have an JavaEE environment with some kind of WebServer or ApplicationServer?

Comment: How do you start your Threads? If you're using `ExecutorService#submit`, you won't have any `Thread` objects in your hand anyway. If you're manually creating `Thread`s (which you shouldn't), you can't really join them using a `ExecutorService`. I suggest you use the same mechanism for joining and forking.

Comment: @Korashen EE environment on a Webserver

Comment: @Oleg In this case I strongly recomment to NOT use custom made threads, as the server will not know about them and they are running out of the servers context. Your webserver should provide you with threadpools, which you can configure via the Admin console. These threadpools are managed and watched by the server. You can get such a threadpool by a simple JNDI lookup or via the context.

Comment: Try one of the following:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html
or
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/java-ee-concurrency-api-tutorial.html
or
just google for it, there is a bunch of different information about Threadpools on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you don't *need* the `Future`s as such, but you can use them to await termination.

Since you're using Java 8, you can do this via

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(kThreads);
container.stream()
    .map(d -> createRunnable(d)) // now you have Runnables
    .map(es::submit) // now they're Futures
    .forEach(Future::get); // get() will wait for futures to finish
```

EDIT:
I just realized that the stream will probably prevent the parallelism to begin with, so you need to collect them intermediately:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = container.stream()
    .map(d -> createRunnable(d)) // now you have Runnables
    .map(es::submit) // now they're Futures
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
futures.forEach(Future::get);
```

Actually, I fully understand that people are confused about having to wait without the futures returning a value. IMO, it would make more sense to have each future return the link of the upload it creates:

```
String scaleAndUpload() {
    BufferedImage scaledBufferedImage=imageService.scale(...);
    imageService.transferToAWS(...);
    return linkToUploadedImage;
}
```

So you would get something like

```
List<Future<?>> futures = container.stream()
    .map(d -> scaleAndUpload()) // now you have Runnables
    .map(es::submit) // now they're Futures
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
return futures.stream()
    .map(Future::get)  // collect the link when the future is finished
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // create a list of them
```

Answer (score 1):

go for the executor service. this gives you many other benefits on top of managing the thread termination (e.g. capacity scaling and separation of execution logic and the actual tasks)

Answer (score 1):

With Executors you just do this.

```
ex.shutdown();
while (!ex.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
}
```

Where ex is your *ExecutorService*. In the loop you can check if your threads are still alive or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use the plain old `Thread` or the `ExecutorService` ?

Use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

> for the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` I must give a certain time that I'm willing to wait but for `Thread.join` I must not.

For proper shutdown of `ExecutorService`:
[How to properly shutdown java ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644043/how-to-properly-shutdown-java-executorservice/36644320#36644320)

A few more alternatives:
[wait until all threads finish their work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `while(!executor.isTerminated) {}`. Then you don't have to say how long you are willing to wait.